# Need a next post button for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a blog and wanted to add a next post button somewhere between every post like this website. http://dose2fun.com

any way to add the button there?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have same to same solution, but you can use jj-wp easy navigation. It will add previous and next post button. It can be controlled by keyboard too.